# Strange behaviour with uppercase Column Names in Doctrine 1.1 resulting in Exception

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, case-sensitive

I have a problem with the case of a column name in Doctrine version 1.1.0.

I have a record (entity) with this definition:

```
abstract class BaseProductsXsell extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('products_xsell');
        $this->hasColumn('ID', 'integer', 4, array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 4, 'primary' => true, 'autoincrement' => true));
        $this->hasColumn('products_id', 'integer', 4, array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 4, 'unsigned' => 1, 'default' => '1', 'notnull' => true));
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

In the MySQL database table the column name of "ID" is upper case, too.
But when I try to fetch the column names after a query with this:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('m.*')->from("ProductsXsell m");
$collection = $query->execute();
$columns = $collection->getTable()->getColumnNames();
print_r($columns);
```

The output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => products_id
    ...
)
```

I have not set the case attribute of the doctrine connection anywhere, so it should be the default value (Doctrine::CASE_NATURAL).

This results in the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Unknown record property / related component "id" on "ProductsXsell"' in /opt/hocatec/bin/libs/Doctrine/Doctrine/Record/Filter/Standard.php:55
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/hocatec/bin/libs/Doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php(1282): Doctrine_Record_Filter_Standard->filterGet(Object(ProductsXsell), 'id')
#1 /opt/hocatec/bin/libs/Doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php(1240): Doctrine_Record->_get('id', true)
#2 /opt/hocatec/bin/libs/Doctrine/Doctrine/Access.php(117): Doctrine_Record->get('id')
#3 /opt/hocatec/bin/models/HocaSync.php(368): Doctrine_Access->offsetGet('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the field that you want to select from your database must to be the same that you defined in your model. Is case sensitive.

You can read more about this [here](https://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/defining-models.html). The first part talk about "Columns" and explain that.

> One problem with database compatibility is that many databases differ
> in their behavior of how the result set of a query is returned. MySQL
> leaves the field names unchanged, which means if you issue a query of
> the form "SELECT myField FROM ..." then the result set will contain
> the field myField.
>
> Unfortunately, this is just the way MySQL and some other databases do
> it. Postgres for example returns all field names in lowercase whilst
> Oracle returns all field names in uppercase. “So what? In what way
> does this influence me when using Doctrine?”, you may ask.
> Fortunately, you don’t have to bother about that issue at all.
>
> Doctrine takes care of this problem transparently. That means if you
> define a derived Record class and define a field called myField you
> will always access it through $record->myField (or $record['myField'],
> whatever you prefer) no matter whether you’re using MySQL or Postgres
> or Oracle etc.
>
> **In short**: You can name your fields however you want, using
> under_scores, camelCase or whatever you prefer.
>
> **NOTE:** In Doctrine columns and column aliases are case sensitive. So when you are using columns in your DQL queries, the column/field names must match the case in your model definition.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference (as I do when editing your answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot! sorry, my  mistake! but I think I was write the essential that was that the name of model must to be the same in his select sentence. Then I put the link for more reference

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not help me with my issue. I have defined the column `ID` in the model, but `$collection->getTable()->getColumnNames()` returns the column in lower case. Why does that happen?

Comment: That occurs because that function calls the function 
    getColumnName()
foreach field of your table and that function returns this:
    strtolower($fieldname);
You can see that in file named "Doctrine_Table"